# Concatenate across rows if value is not zero mySQL

Tags: mysql

I have a table that contains chemical formula information across several columns.

```
|C |H |N |O |S |P |
|12|2 |3 |0 |2 |0 |
|23|12|3 |2 |3 |1 |
```

I am trying to concatenate them to give me the full formula name, but exclude zeroes. It looks like CONCAT_WS can do this, but I want to change the separator to the column name. That is why I have used CONCAT so far:

```
SELECT CONCAT("C", t1.C, "H", t1.H, "N", t1.N, "O", t1.O, "P", t1.P, "S", t1.S) Formula
FROM tmaster AS t1
WHERE t1.S != 0;
```

It's close, but not what I need.

Instead of returning C12H2N3O0S2P0 I want C12H2N3S2, i.e. ignore the cell and separator when the cell value is zero.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I you are stuck with the design you published then you need to test each column for example

```
drop table if exists t;
create table t
(C int,H int,N int,O int,S int,P int);
insert into t values
(12,2 ,3 ,0 ,2 ,0 ),
(23,12,3 ,2 ,3 ,1 );

select concat
        (
        case when c <> 0 then concat('c',c) else '' end,
        case when h <> 0 then concat('h',h) else '' end,
        case when n <> 0 then concat('n',n) else '' end,
        case when o <> 0 then concat('o',o) else '' end,
        case when p <> 0 then concat('p',p) else '' end,
        case when s <> 0 then concat('s',s) else '' end
        ) formula
from t;

+----------------+
| formula        |
+----------------+
| c12h2n3s2      |
| c23h12n3o2p1s3 |
+----------------+
2 rows in set (0.001 sec)
```

Comment: I am indeed stuck with the formatting and this worked a charm. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I'm just going to suggest a more appropriate table design, namely this:

```
id | symbol | quantity | position
1  | C      | 12       | 1
1  | H      | 2        | 2
1  | N      | 3        | 3
1  | O      | 0        | 4
1  | S      | 2        | 5
1  | P      | 0        | 6
2  | C      | 23       | 1
2  | H      | 12       | 2
2  | N      | 3        | 3
2  | O      | 2        | 4
2  | S      | 3        | 5
2  | P      | 1        | 6
```

Now that your data is normalized, we can take advantage of MySQL's aggregate functions to generate the output you want:

```
SELECT
    id,
    GROUP_CONCAT(symbol, quantity ORDER BY position SEPARATOR '') AS formula
FROM yourTable
WHERE
    quantity > 0
GROUP BY
    id;
```

[image: screen capture from demo below]

### Demo